# How to create NestJS middleware wrapper around express middleware with routes?

Tags: nestjs, middleware

Auth0 provides `express-openid-connect`, which produces global middleware with routes. I'd like to make NestJS Middleware that wraps it.

I've created my middleware wrapper:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
import { auth } from 'express-openid-connect';
import { OidcOptions, OIDC_MODULE_OPTIONS } from './oidc';

@Injectable()
export class OidcMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private middleware: RequestHandler;

  constructor(@Inject(OIDC_MODULE_OPTIONS) oidcOptions: OidcOptions) {
    this.middleware = auth({
      ...oidcOptions.configParams
    })
  }

  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    this.middleware(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

and I apply it on the consumer:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [OidcController]
})
export class OidcModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(OidcMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

The problem is that the express middleware has routes, and they aren't being applied in the same way they are when I register the express middleware directly with the app in `main.ts` with the `app.use(auth({...})` pattern. When registered from `main.ts` the `/login` and `/callback` are working. In both cases I've enabled `DEBUG` and confirmed that `express-openid-connect` middleware objects contains the routes; but when using the `NestMiddleware` pattern I think NestJS just returns `404 Not Found` responses since the routes aren't registered with the framework.

I tried registering dummy routes on a dummy controller, but then inside of the `use` method the `req` has already been rewritten, and manually calling the pieces started feeling way too hacky.

What is the conventional method used by NestJS developers to wrap express middleware in a NestJS compatible module?

Comment: Is this middleware supposed to add routes to your application? So it's not _just_ a middleware, but also a partial controller (in that it has internal routes that are being added and acted upon)

Comment: Yes, that's the case, and probably the issue. It seems that in express, "A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system", and the call to `auth` produces such a router instance, of type `RequestHandler`, and it behaves correctly when `app.use()`d, but then I'm forced to work outside of the framework at the express level for the other functionality of the middleware. I'd lose access to my configuration, dependency injection, ...

Comment: Is there a way then to dynamically add the routes of this `RequestHandler` into the Nest router? If I could do that from `OidcModule.consume` that would be pretty perfect.

Comment: For something like this, I probably would suggest just keeping it in the `main.ts`. I don't think the `MiddlewareConsumer` would work for what's happening here. [Here's the relevant code for binding the middleware](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/middleware/middleware-module.ts#L297). One other approach that _might_ work is injecting the `HttpAdapterHost` into a module and usign `onModuleInit` to get the `HttpAdapter` instance and bind the middleware to that using `host.use(middleware)`. Seems kinda hacky though